# Tailwind Border not visible with Angular

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, border

I am trying to use border from Tailwind in my angular project which also uses Material UI, however border is not viisble. In the web developer tool I can see the styles I have used but just not rendering.There no other code in the page except below-

```
  <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
  <div class="col-span-2 border-2 border-indigo-300 bg-gray-300 ">01</div>
  <div class="border-2 border-indigo-600 bg-gray-300">02</div>
  <div class="border-2 border-indigo-600 bg-gray-300">03</div> 
  </div>
```

The page only render 3 grey boxes without any border.

Comment: I tried to recreate this and I could see the borders on the other 2 columns. The first column having `border-indigo-300**` definitely would not show any border because Tailwind does not recognize those asterisks as far as I understand. Now, you are likely not seeing any border at all because of conflicts with Material UI? In dev tools, do you see some Tailwind declarations cancelled? If yes, then css conflicts it is!

Comment: Hi, those asterix were here actually, in the code I do not have. I tried to make them bold in this post and then missed to take off.  In the developer tool, I could see the style (not cancelled) but wasn't redering. However now I have added border-solid which has worked.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed adding **border-solid**

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
 <div class="col-span-2 border border-solid border-indigo-600 bg-gray-300 ">01</div>
  <div class="border border-solid border-indigo-600 bg-gray-300">02</div>
  <div class="border border-solid border-indigo-600 bg-gray-300">03</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What version of tailwind are you using ?
If you imported `@tailwind base;` in your main css file, the `border-solid` is applied by default

Comment: tailwindcss version
3.3.3